# Is f a injective function for the function below

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

I have a question, suppose we have $f:\omega_{1}^* \to \omega_{1}$ satisfies $f(\alpha)<\alpha$, with $\omega_{1}^*=\{\lambda\in \omega_{1} :\lambda \,\text{limit} \}$ can $f$ be injective?

My guess is yes but I don't really know how to approach the problem

Comment: What does "$\omega_1^*=\{\lambda \in \omega_1\,:\,\lambda \,\text {limit}$" mean?

Comment: It is the set in which lambda is in $\omega_1$ and it is a limit ordinal

Comment: If there is such a function, it can't be increasing, since $\omega^\omega$ is the $\omega^\omega$th limit ordinal. It may be possible to reach a contradiction by considering only those $\alpha$ for which $f(\alpha)$ is smaller than all later values of $f$, combined with the fact that $\omega_1$ has uncountable cofinality.

Comment: Using $\omega_1^*$ to denote the limit ordinals is a bit in bad taste, since $\alpha^*$ generally denotes the "reversed order" in order theory...

Comment: Do you know Fodor's lemma?

Comment: I do not know about this Lemma would you be able to explain if?

Comment: @AsafKaragila. Is there a standard notation for the set of limit ordinals in $\omega_1$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet It's standard to write $C'$ for the set of limit points of $C \subseteq \alpha \in \mathrm{Ord}$. So $\omega_1'$ would be the set of limit points of $\omega_1$ which is equal to the set of limit ordinals of $\omega_1$. Another notation I've seen is $\omega_1 \cap \mathrm{Lim}$, where $\mathrm{Lim}$ denotes the class of limit ordinals.

Comment: @StefanMesken. Thank you. I should have recalled that $X' =\{y:y\in Cl(X \setminus \{y\}\}$ is standard notation in topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ cannot be injective. In fact it is constant on a set of size $\aleph_{1}$.

As Asaf already pointed out in the comments, this is due to [Fodor's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor%27s_lemma): $\omega_1^*$ is a stationary subset of $\omega_1$ (since clearly every club $C \subseteq \omega_1$ contains a limit ordinal - in fact the limit points $C' \subseteq C$ forms a smaller club consisting entirely of limit ordinals). Now, because $f$ is decreasing on a stationary subset of $\omega_1$, Fodor's lemma immediately implies that $f$ is constant on a stationary subset of $\omega_1$ and thus it is stationary on a subset of size $\aleph_1$ of $\omega_1$. In particular $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Fodor's lemma is an incredibly useful tool in set theory. Be advised to take careful note not only of its precise statement but also of its proof - it will come in handy.

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you! I will be sure to learn and understand the proof for this lemma.

Comment: @Gibberish You're very welcome!

Comment: Just for fun I posted a proof that does not use Fodor's Lemma. I think the result that a regressive $f:C\to \omega_1$ has an uncountable fiber when $C$ is c.l.u.b. may be from Sierpinski. It is a weak result compared to Fodor's Lemma...........+1

Answer (score 1):

We can also answer this without the Pressing-Down Lemma (Fodor's Lemma) because $\omega_1^*$ is closed and unbounded (c.l.u.b., or "club") in the $\epsilon$-order topology on $\omega_1.$

Extend the domain of $f$ to $\omega_1$ by letting $f(y)=\sup (y\cap \omega_1^*)$ for $y\in \omega_1\setminus \omega_1^*.$ Then $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)<x$ for all  $0<x<\omega_1.$

For each $x$ there is a least finite $H(x)\in \{0\}\cup \Bbb N$ such that $f^{H(x)}(x)=0.$ Otherwise $(f^n(x))_{n\in \Bbb N}$ would be an infinite strictly decreasing sequence of ordinals.

Let $S(n)=H^{-1}\{n\}.$  We have $\omega_1=\cup_{n\in \{0\}\cup \Bbb N\{\infty}S(n)$ so some $S(n)$ is uncountable. Let $n_1$ be the least $n$ such that $S(n)$ is uncountable.  We have $n_1>0$ because $S(0)=\{0\}.$ So $f$ maps $S(n_1)$  to the countable set $S(n_1-1).$ Therefore $\exists x\in S(n_1-1)\;(|f^{-1}\{x\}|=\omega_1).$

Now $(f^{-1}\{x\})\cap \omega_1^*$ is uncountable because $(f^{-1}\{x\}) \setminus \omega_1^*$ is only countable....

....because if $x'$ is the least (or any) member of $\omega_1^*$ that is greater than $x,$ then $x'<y\in \omega_1\setminus \omega_1^*\implies f(y)\geq x'>x,$ so $\sup \;(f^{-1}\{x\})\setminus \omega_1^* \leq  x'.$

BTW. If we substitute an uncountable non-closed set $C$ for $\omega_1^*$, this does not work because  the extension of $f$ to the domain $\omega_1,$ as defined above, will have $f(y)=y$ for some $y>0.$

I remember Prof. William Weiss talking about this in class: The post office has a machine that sorts letters by moving each letters from higher-numbered slots to lower-numbered slots. This worked until there was a letter in every slot numbered  less than $\omega_1$  and the machine jams because uncountably many letters have to go into one slot....